# main content overlaps my footer, responsive layout issues

Tags: css

i have a responsive layout that im working on but having troubles, whenever i try and shrink the browser to reflect mobile view the elements in my container are responsive but they get cut off.... this is due to a overflow hidden property on my container. Now everytime i set it off my elements in the main container appear but they just present them selves over my footer.

is there anyway i can get the footer to be responsive to those elements in the container and move down with the content?

https://trial.nationalpaymentcard.com/FuelMaster/enroll.html   this is the link of what im trying to work on.

please inspect element and help me figure out this puzzle.

Thanks again!

Comment: I'm not so sure about your approach; wouldn't it be more convenient to use the device-related viewport directives instead of resizing?

Comment: the layout is responsive so i figure it wouldve been best :/ im not sure myself

Comment: Well designing a 1024x768 website to be showed on a smartphone is really tricky. Also, recent smartphone have a very high resolution... that's a real headache!

Comment: the funny thing is though that the main page, home page works fine in a responsive layout, its just this enrollment kit thats not works right :/